# Camel component RabbitMQ not durable

Tags: kotlin, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I try to send durable message from Camel component to RabbitMQ. Although default option is true, I set this option explicitly:

```
.to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "rabbitmq:demoExchange?queue=demoQueue" +
        "&guaranteedDeliveries=true" +
        "&mandatory=true" +
        "&autoDelete=false" +
        "&durable=true")
```

Also, I created RabbitMQ component:

```
@Bean("rabbitmq")
fun rabbitMqComponent(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): RabbitMQComponent {
    val rabbitMqComponent = RabbitMQComponent()
    rabbitMqComponent.connectionFactory = connectionFactory
    rabbitMqComponent.isDurable = true

    return rabbitMqComponent
}
```

And my connection factory is:

```
@Bean
fun connectionFactory(): ConnectionFactory {
    val connectionFactory = ConnectionFactory()
    connectionFactory.host = "localhost"
    connectionFactory.port = 5672
    connectionFactory.username = "guest"
    connectionFactory.password = "guest"
    return connectionFactory
}
```

The problem description by steps:

1. Send the message to the broker
2. See the message in RabbitMQ management
3. Stop and start broker by commands:

   ```
   rabbitmq-service stop
   rabbitmq-service start
   ```
4. My queue is absent

How to save the message after server restart?

Also, I tried to make an example with RabbitMQ without Camel and the message was saved after server restart.

Comment: Use a [persistent queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK to have messages that survive a broker restart, you have to met multiple things

- Durable exchange
- Durable queue
- Persistent flag on messages

So I guess with `durable=true` Camel takes care that the first two are met. Perhaps you can double check this in some kind of admin GUI?

However, the third one is missing in your post. The [Rabbit Docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#durability) say

> Durability of a queue does not make messages that are routed to that queue durable

According to the [Camel docs of the Rabbit component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/rabbitmq-component.html) there is a message header `rabbitmq.DELIVERY_MODE` you can set on the Message. The value for `persistent` seems to be `2` (taken from [this tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)).

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, it needed to set header with the key `rabbitmq.DELIVERY_MODE`, for example in route:

```
.setHeader("rabbitmq.DELIVERY_MODE", simple("2"))
```

Here can be 2 values:

1. non persistent
2. persistent

After setting this header the message doesn't disappear after server restart.